# Nested forms in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

As the title I'd like to know how can I nested two forms in Laravel. I know that html 5 doesn't support this thing. So I tried to search a solution on internet and I find the possibility to use the attribute form inside my input. So in my blade file I wrote this outside the first form tag:

```
@foreach($grav as $g)
<form id="update" action="{{ route('Update', ['id' => $g->id_grav]) }}" method="post"class="form-horizontal">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}</form>
  @endforeach
```

And in every input I wrote the attribute `form="update"`
So when I submit I haven't error, but nothing is happening.

So what I have to do?
Thanks

**EDIT**

```
<div id="editgrav-{{$g->id_grav}}"
    class="accordion-body collapse">
<div class="accordion-inner">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <br/>

                <input class="form-control hidden" type="text" name="ids[]" value="{{ $g->id_grav }}" form="update" disabled>
                <!--the rest of form-->
                    <label for="noteGrav"
                            class="control-label col-lg-4">Note:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                <textarea 
                            name="noteGrav"
                            form="updateGrav"
                            class="form-control">{{$g->note_grav}}</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group; col-lg-11"
                        style="text-align:right">
                    <input type="submit"
                            value="Save"
                            form="update"
                            class="btn btn-success btn-sm"/>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show full form code with input elements and submit button.

Comment: I posted only one input and submit button as the form is very long

Comment: just to be sure, as per your code, you are generating several forms, you are not nesting the forms; can you make it a bit clear.

Comment: That piece of code I've posted before is inside another form.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little further; What is the logic behind using nested form?

Answer (score 0):

There can be several forms in a same document. But even in laravel, forms can't be nested

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using several forms and not nesting them; Following are some steps you can isolate and check individually

1. Submit Form by button click. Due to several forms it is possible that the
   form is not getting submitted, if it is the case (that can be
   checked in step 2) try to name all the forms and their elements
   differently, you can do that as you are using a loop just add
   another counter variable and append its value with all element ids
   and names, I can see that you are not adding id. Add id and names
   both for the form elements and forms.
2. If it is submitted you can check that in the update method, just
   return any string from that method that the method is called.
3. If it is getting in the method but not updating the data, try to log
   the request variable, you can use dd($request) or any other logging
   functions.

Let me know if you have performed the steps.

Comment: Using your suggestion I have discovered that the problem is in the $request. Inside the variable there is always the old data, so when I submit, in the db are stored the same data

Comment: Have you added the counter variable with names and ids. as an example, your first form would have an id = update1, 2nd form would be update2

Comment: I wrong before. The problem is not inside the request, but when I try to update the data the form takes always the same id, which is the first.

Comment: try submitting the form with javascript or jQuery, so that you can submit a specific form

Answer (score 0):

use ajax submitting instead of two forms this will help your and let you not use nested form in your code. this is the best approach to solve this error  i have same issue like that and to solve this error i decide to use java script and i just solve my issue by using ajax in my php code.

Comment: I think this is the best way to use nested forms. Do you have any example of this?